# FTPClient java.net.SocketException: Connection reset while reading file

Tags: java, android, ftp

I'm using `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` to download and read data from a 7kb file. It crashes always at the same line (which is at about 50% of the file) with "Connection reset" exception. The server says transfer success.

It's definitely something related with the size, if I replace text with something else it crashes at about the same position and if I delete all the text starting from the line it doesn't crash.

It also happens (always) both in an old remote ftp server as well as my freshly configured unrelated local server. With in combination with the success server output points in the direction of the client as the cause.

```
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username, String password, int port) {
try {
    ftpClient = new FTPClient();

// ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(10000);

    // connecting to the host
    ftpClient.connect(host, port);

    ftpClient.setKeepAlive(true);
    ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(100000);
    ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveReplyTimeout(10000);
    ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(100000);
    ftpClient.setDataTimeout(10000);
    ftpClient.setSoTimeout(100000);

    // now check the reply code, if positive mean connection success
    if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode())) {
        // login using username & password
        boolean status = ftpClient.login(username, password);
        /*
        * Set File Transfer Mode
        * To avoid corruption issue you must specified a correct
        * transfer mode, such as ASCII_FILE_TYPE, BINARY_FILE_TYPE,
        * EBCDIC_FILE_TYPE .etc. Here, I use BINARY_FILE_TYPE for
        * transferring text, image, and compressed files.
        */
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE);
// ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.LOCAL_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE);
        // ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        return status;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Error: could not connect to host " + host + ": " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return false;
}
```

Code to download:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(myPath);

    if (inputStream != null) {
        Map<String, String> stuff= loadStuff(inputStream, languageDescriptor.code);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        return stuff;

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        return null;
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
} finally {
    if (inputStream != null) {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}



private Map<String, String> loadStuff(InputStream inputStream) throws IllegalFormatException {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));


        Map<String, String> stuff= new HashMap<>();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.startsWith(UTF8_BOM)) {
                line = line.substring(1);
            }

            if (line.trim().isEmpty() || line.startsWith("[")) {
                continue;

            } else {
                // parse line, store in map
            }
        }
        return stuff;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server output:

```
(000352)30.05.2017 15:09:50 - test (127.0.0.1)> RETR myfile.lng
(000352)30.05.2017 15:09:50 - test (127.0.0.1)> 150 Opening data channel for file download from server of "/myfile.lng"
(000352)30.05.2017 15:09:50 - test (127.0.0.1)> 226 Successfully transferred "/myfile.lng"
(000352)30.05.2017 15:09:50 - test (127.0.0.1)> QUIT
(000352)30.05.2017 15:09:50 - test (127.0.0.1)> 221 Goodbye
(000352)30.05.2017 15:09:50 - test (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.
```

**Edit:**
Someone requested to show logs from downloading the file from ftp server with a standard ftp client. I used Filezilla.

Connection with local server:

```
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 0
16:29:10    Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21...
16:29:10    Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
16:29:10    Response:   220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
16:29:10    Response:   220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 2
16:29:10    Command:    AUTH TLS
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   502 Explicit TLS authentication not allowed
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 3
16:29:10    Command:    AUTH SSL
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   502 Explicit TLS authentication not allowed
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
16:29:10    Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
16:29:10    Command:    USER test
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   331 Password required for test
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
16:29:10    Command:    PASS *******
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   230 Logged on
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 6
16:29:10    Command:    SYST
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 6
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 7
16:29:10    Command:    FEAT
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   211-Features:
16:29:10    Response:    MDTM
16:29:10    Response:    REST STREAM
16:29:10    Response:    SIZE
16:29:10    Response:    MLST type*;size*;modify*;
16:29:10    Response:    MLSD
16:29:10    Response:    UTF8
16:29:10    Response:    CLNT
16:29:10    Response:    MFMT
16:29:10    Response:    EPSV
16:29:10    Response:    EPRT
16:29:10    Response:   211 End
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 7
16:29:10    Status: Logged in
16:29:10    Trace:  Measured latency of 0 ms
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:29:10    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
16:29:10    Status: Retrieving directory listing...
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 0
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 1
16:29:10    Command:    PWD
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 1
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpListOpData::ListSend() in state 2
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 1
16:29:10    Command:    TYPE I
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   200 Type set to I
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
16:29:10    Command:    PASV
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,239,193)
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
16:29:10    Trace:  Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP 127.0.0.1
16:29:10    Command:    MLSD
16:29:10    Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   150 Opening data channel for directory listing of "/"
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:29:10    Response:   226 Successfully transferred "/"
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 8
16:29:10    Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
16:29:10    Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpListOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 3
16:29:10    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:29:10    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:29:10    Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
16:29:10    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
```

Directly after connection - download file from local server:

```
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 0
16:30:49    Status: Connecting to 127.0.0.1:21...
16:30:49    Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
16:30:49    Response:   220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
16:30:49    Response:   220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 2
16:30:49    Command:    AUTH TLS
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   502 Explicit TLS authentication not allowed
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 3
16:30:49    Command:    AUTH SSL
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   502 Explicit TLS authentication not allowed
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
16:30:49    Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
16:30:49    Command:    USER test
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   331 Password required for test
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::Send() in state 5
16:30:49    Command:    PASS *******
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   230 Logged on
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpLogonOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
16:30:49    Status: Logged in
16:30:49    Trace:  Measured latency of 0 ms
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::FileTransfer()
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::Send() in state 0
16:30:49    Status: Starting download of /en.lng
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 0
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 2
16:30:49    Command:    CWD /
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   250 CWD successful. "/" is current directory.
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::Send() in state 3
16:30:49    Command:    PWD
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpChangeDirOpData::ParseResponse() in state 3
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 1
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 1
16:30:49    Command:    TYPE I
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   200 Type set to I
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 1
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 2
16:30:49    Command:    PASV
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,251,42)
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 2
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 4
16:30:49    Trace:  Binding data connection source IP to control connection source IP 127.0.0.1
16:30:49    Command:    RETR en.lng
16:30:49    Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   150 Opening data channel for file download from server of "/en.lng"
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 4
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 5
16:30:49    Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=2
16:30:49    Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(1)
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
16:30:49    Response:   226 Successfully transferred "/en.lng"
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::ParseResponse() in state 5
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpRawTransferOpData::Send() in state 8
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpFileTransferOpData::SubcommandResult() in state 7
16:30:49    Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
16:30:49    Status: File transfer successful, transferred 6.265 bytes in 1 second
16:30:49    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
16:30:49    Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(0)
```

Comment: Can you download the file using a standalone FTP client, e.g. WinSCP? Show us it log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl done! Appended the logs to the end of my post.

Comment: What log does not show anything. We need to see FTP session transcript.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with a trivial download code like                 `OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(local); ftp.retrieveFile(remote, output); output.close();`

Comment: @MartinPrikryl you're right - in Filezilla I think I have to enable the debug mode. I'll actually look for the detailed log of the FTP server, probably there's also something informative there. Have to do something quickly, will be back in 30 mins!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I set the log mode of Filezilla client to debug and added these logs to the answer. I'm not sure if this output is what you mean with session transcript - if not I couldn't find how to do this with Filezilla. Also couldn't get verbose logs on the server. Let me know if this helps. If it doesn't I'll use another client, with which I can get the session transcript?

Comment: You didn't answer my question above about use of a trivial download code + With FileZilla you are using binary mode, while in your code you are using ascii/text mode. Did you try binary mode with your code? Or even better with my trivial download code.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl sorry missed it! I tried it out now and I get: `org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamException: IOException caught while copying.` Re: binary mode I have also tried that, it was actually my original mode when I got this error and started trying out different things. I also tried it now with the simple download mode.

Comment: And did you check that the file downloaded with FileZilla is complete? + What does `CopyStreamException.getIOException()` return? + Did you try removing all those timeout and keepalive calls (like `ftpClient.setControlKeepAliveTimeout`) - Or did you add those in attempt to fix the problem?

Comment: You said `It crashes always at the same line`. Which line is causing the crash?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl it's something with the (genymotion) simulator. On real devices there are no problems. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Seems to be simulator specific - it happens only in Genymotion.